# Result of math. operation - replace math. formula

Tags: text-editing

If I want to do some math. operation I do next:

(* 5 3)

```
C-x C-e (eval-last-sexp)
```

Here result:

[image]

As you can see the result is in the minibuffer.

Nice.

But I need result to REPLACE math. formula.
I need smt. like this:

[image]
How I can do this?

P.S. Custom function `eval-last-sexp` not work for **multiple cursors**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

First, in case you weren't aware, there's `eval-print-last-sexp`, bound to `C-j` in `lisp-interaction-mode` (for instance in the `*scratch*` buffer), which will print the result after the sexp (instead of displaying it in the echo area, like `eval-last-sexp`, but without deleting the sexp, like you want).

The following function should also delete the sexp, giving the desired effect of replacing the sexp with its desired value.

```elisp
(defun eval-replace-last-sexp ()
  "Evaluate sexp before point; replace sexp with value.

The point will be at the end of the inserted value.  The replaced
sexp will be added to the kill-ring.  If the latter is not
desired, use `delete-region' instead of `kill-region', below."
  (interactive)
    (let ((beg (progn
         (backward-sexp)
         (point)))
      (end (progn
         (forward-sexp)
         (point))))
      ;; the argument of t means that result is printed into the buffer,
      ;; as we want
      (eval-last-sexp t)
      (kill-region beg end)))
```

Now you can call the function directly with `M-x eval-replace-last-sexp` or by binding it to a convenient keyboard short-cut.

Comment: It's not work for multiple cursors. It work only when I has ONE cursor. I update my post.

Comment: Does the built-in `eval-print-last-sexp` (`C-j` in `*scratch*`) work with multiple cursors? (I haven't tested that yet, as I don't use `multiple-cursors`; I'll try to get around to it.)

Comment: Yes, `eval-print-last-sexp` successfully works for multiple cursors ONLY by `C-j`. If I run by name  `eval-print-last-sexp` - than I need run every time this function.

Comment: If I bind keybinding to `eval-print-last-sexp`, e.g. `C-c C-l` and run `eval-print-last-sexp` by shortcut it works with `multiple-cursors`.

Comment: Investigating a bit, I think that it's just the behaviour of multiple cursors. For instance, if you use `M-x kill-line` directly (rather than with `C-k`), then it also won't work with multiple cursors. I believe that the behaviour is intentional and caused by `execute-extended-command` (the function that `M-x` is bound to) being in `mc--default-cmds-to-run-once` ([see here](https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el/blob/6a7c3c0853e3fe9e4b8e5985dbed8fd4075f33ff/multiple-cursors-core.el#L688)). The custom `eval-replace-last-sexp` also seems to work with multiple cursors when bound to a key.

Answer (score 0):

Embedded calc mode might of interest to you. Not for elisp maths, however. Check the emacs calc tutorial (info manual).